# Handling http_request in IE 8, using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-io

i've been working on some kind of remote control for some time now and figured out a problem that confuses me:

The remote controle is supposed to control some kind of machine. The complete hardware based code is written in c by myself, but thats not really interesting for my problem. 
Im using a webserver and a webpage to get access to some basic commands, just like driving forward, backward or turning motor on/off (i use a wlan accesspoint on the board in the machine to connect to it). So far everything works fine, but............:

My Problem is, that there are several options to control the functions of the machine (Terminal, wired-connected Notebook, remote control, "normal" working loop) at the same time. This means, if the machine switches on the motor by itself or a worker uses the terminal, it is neccessary for me to have a feedback on my remote control aswell (at the moment i switch the color of the different button-border from green=inactive to red=active).

The way i did that is easy explained:
If for an example the motor is switched on in c, i write a file with a decimal number that represents a binary code. Just like motor on is 0001 means i write a dec 1. Motor off would be 0010, means i write a dec 2. Because it is possible that there are more than only one function running at the same time i just pass values like 13 (motor on: 0001 = 1; forward: 0100 = 4; lights on: 1000 = 8; => 8+4+1=13). I use a binary AND comparsion to get the actual information about the status afterwards.

Nevertheless i cant refresh the page every two seconds to check the file i write to for changes, im using ajax to have a simple and fancy request possibility:

```
var http_request = false;

    function RequestCommandStatus(url) {

    http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Ended due to an error!');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = control4Commands;
    http_request.send(null);

    }
```

and after that i do the comparsion stuff:

```
        function control4Commands() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        var answer = http_request.responseText; 
        if ((answer & 0x1) == 0x1){
                                 //do something
        }
        if ((answer & 0x2) == 0x2){
                                 //do something
        }
        if ((answer & 0x4) == 0x4){
                                 //do something
        }
        if ((answer & 0x8) == 0x8){
                                 //do something
        }   
    }
    }                                                                   

    setInterval("RequestValveStatus('myfile.txt')", 1000);
```

This works pretty good in Firefox but for some reason i got a strange problem in IE8 (even if i enabled every known scripting language and allowed pretty much complete access and control):

For some reason the request seems to be executed once, but after that there is no more interaction between the page and the server. The value of the file changes like it is supposed to. If i reload the page manualy, and for an example, the motor is still running, it changes the color of the border to red. In my opinion this should make sure that the request atleast succeded once.
By using the script debugger of the developer tools, i got the error message, that the http_request.open() failed because of access denied. My first suggestion was that it might be about the path or the type of the file i read from, but i wasnt able to fix it in IE8 with .html, .php, .txt and "several" other types. Also changing the path/origin didnt solved the problem.

I'd really like to discuss this problem with you and feel free to post me your ideas about this way of getting the actual status of the functions.

Greeting,

Ohemgi

I'm sorry for my bad english. Feel free to ask if you cant follow my explanations :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
setInterval("RequestValveStatus('myfile.txt')", 1000);
```

into

```
setInterval(function() { RequestValveStatus('myfile.txt'); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Actually this changed nothing. Its is doing same like before. Still good in firefox - succeding only once in ie8 and freezing after.